# How to implement a constraint solver for 2-D geometry?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, integer-programming

I have a set of metallic sliding pieces which are constrained to the x and y axis in following way:

[image: sliding pieces]

I would need to maximize the horizontal distance among all pieces constrained by the same slider and the vertical distance among the sliding pieces and the sliders itself. How can this be solved?

Any advice and suggestion which can lead to a solution for this problem would be greatly appreciated.

I looked first at some very powerful libraries like cassowary and jsLPSolver but i had some trouble to understand the core algorithm and how the constraint are checked for feasibility and how the possible solutions are then ranked.

How could be implemented in JavaScript a (simple) stub for a 2-D geometric constraint solver for problems like this one above?

EDIT:

I have following input data:

```
maxW = 300, maxH = 320
```

The pieces are defined as follows (not mandatory, every solution is accepted):

```
slidingPiece = [pX, pY, width, height, anchorPoint, loopDistance];
```

I will try to explain what i mean under "maximize".

Horizontal spacing:

a0-b1, b1-b2, b2-b4, b4-b5 and b5-maxX will be the same, i.e. max X divided by the greatest number of vertical intersecting pieces + 1 (5).
b1-b3 and b3-b5 will be then determined by the available remaining space.

Vertical spacing:

b1-a3, a3-a4 and a0-b5 will be the same. Ideally, a0-b3,b3-b4,a2-b2,b4-a3 and b2-a4 will be also the same value. Maximizing a1-b4 and b3-a2 is the same as maximizing b3-b4. The same applies to a2-b2 and b4-a3: the distance b2-b4 will be then the max negative value.

So, i need to maximize the distance among every sliding piece and his nearest above or below Y-constraint.

The 2-D geometric representation of this problem shows that the horizontal spacing depends from the vertical distance of the anchors (due to the vertical intersection of the anchored pieces), which in turn depends from the horizontal position of the pieces itself. Think for example, b2 is somewhat shorter above. In this case, b1 and b2 are no longer intersecting and would became the same x value, i.e. max X divided by 4.

In some other cases, for example b2 is much longer in the above part - and will cross the anchor a2, then it shall be spaced to a1. This is the reason because there will be a set of solutions, some feasible and some other not, because for example, the global max Y constraint would be broken.

Comment: do you have some more data, or some values to show what you want?

Comment: you could add the numerical data as well, not only a picture, on which (for me) is not really to see, what you need.

Comment: I think that you should write the objective function for your task. And use any algorithm for optimization. For example, the simplex method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

Comment: "the vertical distance among the sliding pieces and the sliders itself." Could you rephrase that? Starting with "slider**s** itself". What do you call the distance between a sliding piece and a slider? Is it the minimal distance between a sliding piece and a slider (i.e. the tip of the piece and another slider?). Those large sliding pieces with a long loop: how do you define the "distance to the slider"?

Comment: @stdob-- Very likely the objective map will be full of local optima. Given the dimension of the problem though (5 sliding pieces on x axis and 5 sliders on y axis), I'd try first a pure Monte Carlo exploration to find a narrower region as the initial position(s) for another optimisation method.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I think you're right.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: thank you to point out that the word "maximize" is very often misused, this applies also to me. I hope my explanation is somewhat cleaner now.

Comment: @NinaScholz: i added some values from the real world and a helper fiddle to visualize the possible positioning of the pieces.

Comment: @deblocker, please add some explanation of the data arrays `a` and `b`. what mean the columns? is the `feasible` array given? or just to generate some result?

Comment: @NinaScholz: i added details of the columns here: https://jsfiddle.net/0ntbkg1r/2/, the feasible array was just composed by hand but i have a lot of sample data to test many scenarios.

Comment: @NinaScholz: beautiful mathematical mind, as i am really interested in this topic,could  you please post a constructive comment where did you find the hardest key points to solve this question?

Comment: my problem is to get a litteral clear picture of the data you have. i tried to implement a data structure to get all information into some kind of object for the rules and the constraints, but it takes more time, than expected, and i don't have the silence this actually to do.
in the data structure i thought, you need to separate between given points and variable points, which are calculated, the next step would be to create some function for fitness, that means the position is weighted against other positions and return some kind of error, which is in the best case zero.

Comment: then i would take another function to move the whole constrution a bit to minimize (the greatest) error, judge again and repeat with moving. but that is very hard with dependent constraints, like you have here. for starting, you could reduce all constraints to a very simple approach and try to solve it dynamically. then proceed with an additional step and go ahead until you reach your full problem.

Comment: you may reach some main problems with generated solution of this kind, first of all, there is no solution, then some solutions are not reachable with mathematical algos, because you need a random factor in it, or you withness a flip-flop or a ring over more positions, which does not reduce the error.

if you really know your problem and it takes to long or is not solvable in this system, you might think of a genetic algo, which could help but needs more preparation and testing.

Answer (score 6):

I would try field approach similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18901490/2521214).

1. **Each slider will retract all sliders away**

   with force scaled by distance^2 like all of them would have the same polarity electric charge or springs attached in between each other.
2. **On top of that add friction scaled by speed**

   does not really matter if air `v^2` or liquid `v^3`
3. **implement kinematic constraints**

   for horizontal and vertical only sliding it should be really easy.
4. **Do physical simulation and wait until it converges to stable state `v=~0`**

   if hit local min/max shake the whole thing a bit or arrange the whole thing randomly and try again. You can do this also to get another solution.

**[Edit4] C++ solver example**

1. **structures/classes to represent the slider system**

   To ease up later code I will not support closed loops or double anchoring. That is why the i1 slider (most right) is not anchored to anything (will just provide forcefield).
   I ended up with this slider definition:

   [image: slider def]

   look at the source of `class _slider` for more info.
2. **render**

   Dash-dash means fixed slider. Silver ones are horizontal, aqua means vertical and yellow is selected by mouse. May be later on red will mean some kind of error/stuck or something for debug purposes. For force field solvers I sometimes add the field strength as red-blue scale but not sure if I will implement it here or not.

   To keep this simple I will not implement zoom/pan functions as your dimensions are convenient for direct render without transforms.

   [image: initial positions]
3. **implement initial setup**

   ```cpp
   sliders sys;
   int i0,i1,a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5;
   sys.slider_beg();//ia,ib,   x,    y,    a0,    a1,    b0,    b1,_horizontal
   i0=sys.slider_add(-1,-1, 25.0, 25.0,  -5.0, 405.0,   0.0,   0.0, 0);
   a0=sys.slider_add(i0,-1,  0.0,  0.0,   0.0, 400.0,   0.0,   0.0, 1);
   a1=sys.slider_add(i0,-1,  0.0,100.0,   0.0, 400.0,   0.0,   0.0, 1);
   a2=sys.slider_add(i0,-1,  0.0,200.0,   0.0, 400.0,   0.0,   0.0, 1);
   a3=sys.slider_add(i0,-1,  0.0,300.0,   0.0, 400.0,   0.0,   0.0, 1);
   a4=sys.slider_add(i0,-1,  0.0,400.0,   0.0, 400.0,   0.0,   0.0, 1);
   b1=sys.slider_add(a0,a2, 20.0,  0.0,   0.0, 125.0, 125.0, 250.0, 0);
   b2=sys.slider_add(a3,-1, 40.0,  0.0, -70.0,  30.0,   0.0,   0.0, 0);
   b3=sys.slider_add(a1,-1, 60.0,  0.0, -70.0,  30.0,   0.0,   0.0, 0);
   b4=sys.slider_add(a2,-1, 80.0,  0.0, -30.0,  70.0,   0.0,   0.0, 0);
   b5=sys.slider_add(a3,a1,100.0,  0.0,-125.0,   0.0,-125.0,-250.0, 0);
   i1=sys.slider_add(-1,-1,425.0, 25.0,  -5.0, 405.0,   0.0,   0.0, 0);
   sys.slider_end();
   ```

   Where `ia` is parent index and `ib` is child index (the slider class itself holds `ib` as parent but that would be confusing to init as you would need to link to item that do not exist yet so the `ib` transformation is handled in the `sys.add` function). `sys` is class holding the whole thing and `sys.add` just add new slider to it and returns its index counting from zero. The `x,y` is relative position to parent.

   To ease up amount of coding this setup must not conflict the constraints. The overview of this setup is in previous bullet.

   Beware the order of sliders must be left to right for vertical and top to bottom for horizontal sliders to ensure correct constraint functionality.
4. **mouse interaction**

   just simple slider movement for debug and adjusting initial setup values. And or handling stuck cases. You need to handle mouse events, select closest slider if not editing already. And if mouse button is pressed move selected slider to mouse position...
5. **physical constraint/interaction**

   I simplify this a bit so I just created a predicate function that is called for specified slider and it returns if it or any its child/anchor is in conflict with defined constraints. This is much more easy to code and debug then to update the position to match actual constraint.

   Usage is then a bit more code. First store actual position for updated slider. Then update slider to new position/state. After that if constraints are not met stop actual slider speeds and restore its original position.

   It will be a bit slower but I am too lazy to code the full constraint updater (that code could get really complex...).

   I recognize 2 interactions parallel and perpendicular. The parallel is straight forward. But the perpendicular is interaction between edge of slider and perpendicular sliders near it not including the already intersecting sliders (a,b anchored or just crossing) during initial state. So I created a list of intersecting sliders (`ic`) at start which will be ignored for this interaction.
6. **physical simulation**

   Simple [Newton - D'Alembert physics for non relativistic speeds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19764828/2521214) will do. Just on each iteration set the accelerations `ax,ay` to the field strength and frictions.
7. **field solver**

   This is set of rules/equations to set simulation accelerations for each slider to converge to solution. I ended up with electrostatic retracting force `F = -Q/r^2` and linear dampening of speed. Also have implemented absolute velocity and acceleration limiters to avoid numeric problems.

   To boost solution time and stability I added precision control modes where the electric charge is lowering when overall max speed of sliders is decreasing.

Here The full **C++/VCL** class code for this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- Sliders solver ver: 1.01 ----------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _sliders_h
#define _sliders_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <math.h>
#include "list.h"   // linear dynamic array template List<T> similar to std::vector
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const double _slider_w   =   3.00;  // [px] slider half width (for rendering)
const double _slider_gap =   4.00;  // [px] min gap between sliders (for colisions)
const double _acc_limit=   100.00;  // [px/s^2]
const double _vel_limit=   100.00;  // [px/s]
const double _friction =     0.90;  // [-]
const double _charge   =250000.00;  // [px^3/s^2]
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class _slider   // one slider (helper class)
    {
public:
    // properties
    double x,y;             // actual relative pos
    bool _horizontal;       // orientation
    double a0,a1;           // slider vertexes 0 is anchor point
    double b0,b1;           // anchor zone for another slider
    int ia;                 // -1 for fixed or index of parrent slider
    int ib;                 // -1 or index of parrent slider
    // computed
    List<int> ic;           // list of slider indexes to ignore for perpendicular constraints
    double a,b;             // force field affected part
    double X,Y;             // actual absolute position
    double vx,vy,ax,ay;     // actual relative vel,acc
    // temp
    int flag;               // temp flag for simulation
    double x0,x1;           // temp variables for solver
    // constructors (can ignore this)
    _slider()           {}
    _slider(_slider& a) { *this=a; }
    ~_slider()          {}
    _slider* operator = (const _slider *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //_slider* operator = (const _slider &a) { ...copy... return this; }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class sliders   // whole slider system main class
    {
public:
    List<_slider> slider;           // list of sliders

    double vel_max;                 // max abs velocity of sliders for solver precision control
    double charge;                  // actual charge of sliders for solve()
    int    mode;                    // actual solution precision control mode

    // constructors (can ignore this)
    sliders();
    sliders(sliders& a) { *this=a; }
    ~sliders()          {}
    sliders* operator = (const sliders *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //sliders* operator = (const sliders &a) { ...copy... return this; }

    // VCL window API variables (can ignore this)
    double mx0,my0,mx1,my1; // last and actual mouse position
    TShiftState sh0,sh1;    // last and actual mouse buttons and control keys state
    int sel;

    // API (this is important stuff)
    void slider_beg(){ slider.num=0; }  // clear slider list
    int  slider_add(int ia,int ib,double x,double y,double a0,double a1,double b0,double b1,bool _h); // add slider to list
    void slider_end();              // compute slider parameters
    bool constraints(int ix);       // return true if constraints hit
    void positions();               // recompute absolute positions
    void update(double dt);         // update physics simulation with time step dt [sec]
    void solve(bool _init=false);   // set sliders accelerations to solve this
    void stop();                    // stop all movements
    // VCL window API for interaction with GUI (can ignore this)
    void mouse(int x,int y,TShiftState sh);
    void draw(TCanvas *scr);
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
sliders::sliders()
    {
    mx0=0.0; my0=0.0;
    mx1=0.0; my1=0.0;
    sel=-1;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int sliders::slider_add(int ia,int ib,double x,double y,double a0,double a1,double b0,double b1,bool _h)
    {
    _slider s; double q;
    if (a0>a1) { q=a0; a0=a1; a1=q; }
    if (b0>b1) { q=b0; b0=b1; b1=q; }
    s.x=x; s.vx=0.0; s.ax=0.0;
    s.y=y; s.vy=0.0; s.ay=0.0;
    s.ia=ia; s.a0=a0; s.a1=a1;
    s.ib=-1; s.b0=b0; s.b1=b1;
    s.ic.num=0;
    if ((ib>=0)&&(ib<slider.num)) slider[ib].ib=slider.num;
    s._horizontal=_h;
    s.a=a0; // min
    if (s.a>a1) s.a=a1;
    if (s.a>b0) s.a=b0;
    if (s.a>b1) s.a=b1;
    s.b=a0; // max
    if (s.b<a1) s.b=a1;
    if (s.b<b0) s.b=b0;
    if (s.b<b1) s.b=b1;
    slider.add(s);
    return slider.num-1;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void sliders::slider_end()
    {
    int i,j;
    double a0,a1,b0,b1,x0,x1,w=_slider_gap;
    _slider *si,*sj;
    positions();
    // detect intersecting sliders and add them to propriet ic ignore list
    for (si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++)
     for (sj=si+1   ,j=i+1;j<slider.num;j++,sj++)
      if (si->_horizontal!=sj->_horizontal)
        {
        if (si->_horizontal)
            {
            a0=si->X+si->a; a1=sj->X-w;
            b0=si->X+si->b; b1=sj->X+w;
            x0=si->Y;       x1=sj->Y;
            }
        else{
            a0=si->Y+si->a; a1=sj->Y-w;
            b0=si->Y+si->b; b1=sj->Y+w;
            x0=si->X;       x1=sj->X;
            }
        if (((a0<=b1)&&(b0>=a1))||((a1<=b0)&&(b1>=a0)))
         if ((x0>x1+sj->a-w)&&(x0<x1+sj->b+w))
            {
            si->ic.add(j);
            sj->ic.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool sliders::constraints(int ix)
    {
    int i,j;
    double a0,a1,b0,b1,x0,x1,x,w=_slider_gap;
    _slider *si,*sj,*sa,*sb,*s;
    s=slider.dat+ix;
    // check parallel neighbors overlapp
    for (si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++)
     if ((i!=ix)&&(si->_horizontal==s->_horizontal))
        {
        if (s->_horizontal)
            {
            a0=s->X+s->a; a1=si->X+si->a;
            b0=s->X+s->b; b1=si->X+si->b;
            x0=s->Y;      x1=si->Y;
            }
        else{
            a0=s->Y+s->a; a1=si->Y+si->a;
            b0=s->Y+s->b; b1=si->Y+si->b;
            x0=s->X;      x1=si->X;
            }
        if (((a0<=b1)&&(b0>=a1))||((a1<=b0)&&(b1>=a0)))
            {
            if ((i<ix)&&(x0<x1+w)) return true;
            if ((i>ix)&&(x0>x1-w)) return true;
            }
        }
    // check perpendicular neighbors overlapp
    for (si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++)
     if ((i!=ix)&&(si->_horizontal!=s->_horizontal))
        {
        // skip ignored sliders for this
        for (j=0;j<s->ic.num;j++)
         if (s->ic[j]==i) { j=-1; break; }
          if (j<0) continue;
        if (s->_horizontal)
            {
            a0=s->X+s->a; a1=si->X-w;
            b0=s->X+s->b; b1=si->X+w;
            x0=s->Y;      x1=si->Y;
            }
        else{
            a0=s->Y+s->a; a1=si->Y-w;
            b0=s->Y+s->b; b1=si->Y+w;
            x0=s->X;      x1=si->X;
            }
        if (((a0<=b1)&&(b0>=a1))||((a1<=b0)&&(b1>=a0)))
         if ((x0>x1+si->a-w)&&(x0<x1+si->b+w))
          return true;
        }
    // conflict a anchor area of parent?
    if (s->ia>=0)
        {
        si=slider.dat+s->ia;
        if (s->_horizontal)
            {
            x0=si->Y+si->a0;
            x1=si->Y+si->a1;
            x=s->Y;
            }
        else{
            x0=si->X+si->a0;
            x1=si->X+si->a1;
            x=s->X;
            }
        if (x<x0+w) return true;
        if (x>x1-w) return true;
        }
    // conflict b anchor area of parent?
    if (s->ib>=0)
        {
        si=slider.dat+s->ib;
        if (si->_horizontal)
            {
            x0=si->X+si->b0;
            x1=si->X+si->b1;
            x=s->X;
            }
        else{
            x0=si->Y+si->b0;
            x1=si->Y+si->b1;
            x=s->Y;
            }
        if (x<x0+w) return true;
        if (x>x1-w) return true;
        }
    // conflict b anchor area with childs?
    for (si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++)
     if ((i!=ix)&&(si->ib==ix))
        {
        if (s->_horizontal)
            {
            x0=s->X+s->b0;
            x1=s->X+s->b1;
            x=si->X;
            }
        else{
            x0=s->Y+s->b0;
            x1=s->Y+s->b1;
            x=si->Y;
            }
        if (x<x0+w) return true;
        if (x>x1-w) return true;
        }

    // check childs too
    for (si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++)
     if ((i!=ix)&&(si->ia==ix))
      if (constraints(i)) return true;
    return false;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void sliders::positions()
    {
    int i,e;
    _slider *si,*sa;
    // set flag = uncomputed
    for (si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++) si->flag=0;
    // iterate until all sliders are computed
    for (e=1;e;)
     for (e=0,si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++)
      if (!si->flag)
        {
        // fixed
        if (si->ia<0)
            {
            si->X=si->x;
            si->Y=si->y;
            si->flag=1;
            continue;
            }
        // a anchored
        sa=slider.dat+si->ia;
        if (sa->flag)
            {
            si->X=sa->X+si->x;
            si->Y=sa->Y+si->y;
            si->flag=1;
            continue;
            }
        e=1; // not finished yet
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void sliders::update(double dt)
    {
    int i;
    _slider *si,*sa;
    double x,X;
    // D'Lamnbert integration
    for (si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++)
     if (si->_horizontal)
        {
        x=si->y; si->vy+=si->ay*dt;     // vel = Integral(acc*dt)
                 si->vy*=_friction;     // friction k*vel
        X=si->Y; si->y +=si->vy*dt;     // pos = Integral(vel*dt)
        positions();                    // recompute childs
        if ((si->ia<0)||(constraints(i))) // if fixed or constraint hit (stop and restore original position)
            {
            si->vy=0.0;
            si->y =x;
            si->Y =X;
            positions();                // recompute childs
            }
        }
    else{
        x=si->x; si->vx+=si->ax*dt;     // vel = Integral(acc*dt)
                 si->vx*=_friction;     // friction k*vel
        X=si->X; si->x +=si->vx*dt;     // pos = Integral(vel*dt)
        positions();                    // recompute childs
        if ((si->ia<0)||(constraints(i))) // if fixed or constraint hit (stop and restore original position)
            {
            si->vx=0.0;
            si->x =x;
            si->X =X;
            positions();                // recompute childs
            }
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void sliders::solve(bool _init)
    {
    int i,j,k;
    double a0,a1,b0,b1,x0,x1;
    _slider *si,*sj,*sa;
    // init solution
    if (_init)
        {
        mode=0;
        charge=_charge;
        }
    // clear accelerations and compute actual max velocity
    vel_max=0.0;
    for (si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++)
        {
        si->ax=0.0;
        si->ay=0.0;
        x0=fabs(si->vx); if (vel_max<x0) vel_max=x0;
        x0=fabs(si->vy); if (vel_max<x0) vel_max=x0;
        }
    // precision control of solver
    if ((mode==0)&&(vel_max>25.0)) { mode++; }                  // wait until speed raises
    if ((mode==1)&&(vel_max<10.0)) { mode++; charge*=0.10; }    // scale down forces to lower jitter
    if ((mode==2)&&(vel_max< 1.0)) { mode++; charge*=0.10; }    // scale down forces to lower jitter
    if ((mode==3)&&(vel_max< 0.1)) { mode++; charge =0.00; stop(); } // solution found
    // set x0 as 1D vector to closest parallel neighbor before and x1 after
    for (si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++) { si->x0=0.0; si->x1=0.0; }
    for (si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++)
     for (sj=si+1   ,j=i+1;j<slider.num;j++,sj++)
      if (si->_horizontal==sj->_horizontal)
        {
        // longer side interaction
        if (si->_horizontal)
            {
            a0=si->X+si->a; a1=sj->X+sj->a;
            b0=si->X+si->b; b1=sj->X+sj->b;
            x0=si->Y;       x1=sj->Y;
            }
        else{
            a0=si->Y+si->a; a1=sj->Y+sj->a;
            b0=si->Y+si->b; b1=sj->Y+sj->b;
            x0=si->X;       x1=sj->X;
            }
        if (((a0<=b1)&&(b0>=a1))||((a1<=b0)&&(b1>=a0)))
            {
            x0=x1-x0;
            if ((si->ia>=0)&&(x0<0.0)&&((fabs(si->x0)<_slider_gap)||(fabs(si->x0)>fabs(x0)))) si->x0=-x0;
            if ((si->ia>=0)&&(x0>0.0)&&((fabs(si->x1)<_slider_gap)||(fabs(si->x1)>fabs(x0)))) si->x1=-x0;
            if ((sj->ia>=0)&&(x0<0.0)&&((fabs(sj->x0)<_slider_gap)||(fabs(sj->x0)>fabs(x0)))) sj->x0=+x0;
            if ((sj->ia>=0)&&(x0>0.0)&&((fabs(sj->x1)<_slider_gap)||(fabs(sj->x1)>fabs(x0)))) sj->x1=+x0;
            }
        // shorter side interaction
        if (si->_horizontal)
            {
            a0=si->Y-_slider_gap; a1=sj->Y+_slider_gap;
            b0=si->Y+_slider_gap; b1=sj->Y+_slider_gap;
            x0=si->X;             x1=sj->X;
            }
        else{
            a0=si->X-_slider_gap; a1=sj->X+_slider_gap;
            b0=si->X+_slider_gap; b1=sj->X+_slider_gap;
            x0=si->Y;             x1=sj->Y;
            }
        if (((a0<=b1)&&(b0>=a1))||((a1<=b0)&&(b1>=a0)))
            {
            if (x0<x1) { x0+=si->b; x1+=sj->a; }
            else       { x0+=si->a; x1+=sj->b; }
            x0=x1-x0;
            if (si->ia>=0)
                {
                sa=slider.dat+si->ia;
                if ((sa->ia>=0)&&(x0<0.0)&&((fabs(sa->x0)<_slider_gap)||(fabs(sa->x0)>fabs(x0)))) sa->x0=-x0;
                if ((sa->ia>=0)&&(x0>0.0)&&((fabs(sa->x1)<_slider_gap)||(fabs(sa->x1)>fabs(x0)))) sa->x1=-x0;
                }
            if (sj->ia>=0)
                {
                sa=slider.dat+sj->ia;
                if ((sa->ia>=0)&&(x0<0.0)&&((fabs(sa->x0)<_slider_gap)||(fabs(sa->x0)>fabs(x0)))) sa->x0=+x0;
                if ((sa->ia>=0)&&(x0>0.0)&&((fabs(sa->x1)<_slider_gap)||(fabs(sa->x1)>fabs(x0)))) sa->x1=+x0;
                }
            }
        }
    // set x0 as 1D vector to closest perpendicular neighbor before and x1 after
    for (si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++)
     for (sj=si+1   ,j=i+1;j<slider.num;j++,sj++)
      if (si->_horizontal!=sj->_horizontal)
        {
        // skip ignored sliders for this
        for (k=0;k<si->ic.num;k++)
         if (si->ic[k]==j) { k=-1; break; }
          if (k<0) continue;
        if (si->_horizontal)
            {
            a0=si->X+si->a; a1=sj->X-_slider_w;
            b0=si->X+si->b; b1=sj->X+_slider_w;
            x0=si->Y;
            }
        else{
            a0=si->Y+si->a; a1=sj->Y-_slider_w;
            b0=si->Y+si->b; b1=sj->Y+_slider_w;
            x0=si->X;
            }
        if (((a0<=b1)&&(b0>=a1))||((a1<=b0)&&(b1>=a0)))
            {
            if (si->_horizontal)
                {
                a1=sj->Y+sj->a;
                b1=sj->Y+sj->b;
                }
            else{
                a1=sj->X+sj->a;
                b1=sj->X+sj->b;
                }
            a1-=x0; b1-=x0;
            if (fabs(a1)<fabs(b1)) x0=-a1; else x0=-b1;
            if ((si->ia>=0)&&(x0<0.0)&&((fabs(si->x0)<_slider_gap)||(fabs(si->x0)>fabs(x0)))) si->x0=+x0;
            if ((si->ia>=0)&&(x0>0.0)&&((fabs(si->x1)<_slider_gap)||(fabs(si->x1)>fabs(x0)))) si->x1=+x0;
            if (sj->ia<0) continue;
            sa=slider.dat+sj->ia;
            if ((sa->ia>=0)&&(x0<0.0)&&((fabs(sa->x0)<_slider_gap)||(fabs(sa->x0)>fabs(x0)))) sa->x0=-x0;
            if ((sa->ia>=0)&&(x0>0.0)&&((fabs(sa->x1)<_slider_gap)||(fabs(sa->x1)>fabs(x0)))) sa->x1=-x0;
            }
        }
    // convert x0,x1 distances to acceleration
    for (si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++)
        {
        // driving force F = ~ Q / r^2
        if (fabs(si->x0)>1e-10)  x0=charge/(si->x0*si->x0); else x0=0.0; if (si->x0<0.0) x0=-x0;
        if (fabs(si->x1)>1e-10)  x1=charge/(si->x1*si->x1); else x1=0.0; if (si->x1<0.0) x1=-x1;
        a0=x0+x1;
        // limit acc
        if (a0<-_acc_limit) a0=-_acc_limit;
        if (a0>+_acc_limit) a0=+_acc_limit;
        // store parallel acc to correct axis
        if (si->_horizontal) si->ay=a0;
         else                si->ax=a0;
        // limit vel (+/- one iteration overlap)
        if (si->_horizontal) x0=si->vy;
         else                x0=si->vx;
        if (x0<-_vel_limit)  x0=-_vel_limit;
        if (x0>+_vel_limit)  x0=+_vel_limit;
        if (si->_horizontal) si->vy=x0;
         else                si->vx=x0;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void sliders::stop()
    {
    int i;
    _slider *si;
    for (si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++)
        {
        si->vx=0.0;
        si->vy=0.0;
        si->ax=0.0;
        si->ay=0.0;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void sliders::mouse(int x,int y,TShiftState sh)
    {
    int i,q0,q1;
    double d,dd;
    _slider *si;
    // update mouse state
    mx0=mx1; my0=my1; sh0=sh1;
    mx1=x;   my1=y;   sh1=sh;
    // slider movement with left mouse button
    q0=sh0.Contains(ssLeft);
    q1=sh1.Contains(ssLeft);
    if ((sel>=0)&&(q1))
        {
        si=slider.dat+sel;
        // stop simulation for selected slider
        si->vx=0.0;
        si->vy=0.0;
        si->ax=0.0;
        si->ay=0.0;
        // use mouse position instead
        if (si->ia>=0)
            {
            if (si->_horizontal){ d=si->y; dd=si->Y; si->y+=my1-si->Y; si->Y=my1; si->vy=0.0; si->ay=0.0; positions(); if (constraints(sel)) { si->y=d; si->Y=dd; positions(); }}
             else               { d=si->x; dd=si->X; si->x+=mx1-si->X; si->X=mx1; si->vx=0.0; si->ax=0.0; positions(); if (constraints(sel)) { si->x=d; si->X=dd; positions(); }}
            }
        }
    // select slider (if not left mouse button used)
    if (!q1)
     for (sel=-1,d=_slider_w+1.0,si=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,si++)
        {
        dd=_slider_w+1.0;
        if (si->_horizontal){ if ((mx1>=si->X+si->a)&&(mx1<=si->X+si->b)) dd=fabs(my1-si->Y); }
         else               { if ((my1>=si->Y+si->a)&&(my1<=si->Y+si->b)) dd=fabs(mx1-si->X); }
        if ((dd<d)&&(dd<=_slider_w)) { sel=i; d=dd; }
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void sliders::draw(TCanvas *scr)
    {
    int i,j,n;
    double w=_slider_w,r,x,y,a0,a1;
    AnsiString txt;
    _slider *s;
    scr->Brush->Style=bsClear;
    #define _line(aa,bb)           \
    if (s->_horizontal)            \
        {                          \
        scr->MoveTo(s->X+aa,s->Y); \
        scr->LineTo(s->X+bb,s->Y); \
        }                          \
    else{                          \
        scr->MoveTo(s->X,s->Y+aa); \
        scr->LineTo(s->X,s->Y+bb); \
        }
    scr->Pen->Color=clSilver;
    scr->Font->Color=clWhite;
    scr->TextOutA(40,40,AnsiString().sprintf("mode %i",mode));
    scr->TextOutA(40,60,AnsiString().sprintf("vel: %.3lf [px/s]",vel_max));
    scr->TextOutA(40,80,AnsiString().sprintf("  Q: %.3lf [px^3/s^2]",charge));
    scr->Font->Color=clYellow;
    for (s=slider.dat,i=0;i<slider.num;i++,s++)
        {
        if (s->_horizontal) scr->Pen->Color=clSilver;
         else               scr->Pen->Color=clAqua;
        if (i==sel)
            {
            scr->Pen->Color=clYellow;
            txt=AnsiString().sprintf(" ix:%i ia:%i ib:%i ic:",sel,s->ia,s->ib);
            for (j=0;j<=s->ic.num;j++) txt+=AnsiString().sprintf(" %i",s->ic[j]);
            scr->TextOutA(40,100,txt);
            scr->TextOutA(40,120,AnsiString().sprintf("pos: %.1lf %.1lf [px]",s->X,s->Y));
            scr->TextOutA(40,140,AnsiString().sprintf("vel: %.3lf %.3lf [px/s]",s->vx,s->vy));
            scr->TextOutA(40,160,AnsiString().sprintf("acc: %.3lf %.3lf [px/s^2]",s->ax,s->ay));
            scr->Pen->Color=clYellow;
            }
        if (s->ia<0) scr->Pen->Style=psDash;
         else        scr->Pen->Style=psSolid;
        // a anchor loop
        x=s->X;
        y=s->Y;
        if (s->ia>=0) scr->Ellipse(x-w,y-w,x+w,y+w);
        // b anchor loop
        r=0.5*fabs(s->b1-s->b0);
        if (s->_horizontal)
            {
            x=s->X+0.5*(s->b0+s->b1);
            y=s->Y;
            scr->RoundRect(x-r,y-w,x+r,y+w,w,w);
            }
        else{
            x=s->X;
            y=s->Y+0.5*(s->b0+s->b1);
            scr->RoundRect(x-w,y-r,x+w,y+r,w,w);
            }
        // a line cutted by a anchor loop
        a0=s->a0; a1=s->a1;
        if ((s->ia>=0)&&(a0<=+w)&&(a1>=-w))
            {
            if (a0<-w) _line(s->a0,-w);
            if (a1>+w) _line( w,s->a1);
            }
        else _line(s->a0,s->a1);
        }
    scr->Font->Color=clDkGray;
    scr->Pen->Style=psSolid;
    scr->Brush->Style=bsSolid;
    #undef _line
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can ignore the VCL stuff it is just API for interaction with my App window and rendering. The solver itself does not need anything from it. I used my dynamic linear array template `List<T>` so here few explanations:

- `List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`
- `xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list
- `xxx[7]` access array element (safe)
- `xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)
- `xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array
- `xxx.reset()` clears the array and set `xxx.num=0`
- `xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

Usage is simple after proper init from bullet **#3** like this:

```
sys.solve(true);
for (;;)
 {
 sys.solve();
 sys.update(0.040); // just time step
 if (sys.mode==4) break; // stop if solution found or stuck
 }
```

Instead of for cycle I call this in timer and redraw the window so I see the animation:

[image: animation]

The choppyness is due to non uniform **GIF** grabbing sample rate (skipping some frames from the simulation irregularly).

You can play with the constants for `vel,acc` limits, dampening coefficient and the mode control `if`s to change the behavior. If you implement also mouse handler then you can move the sliders with left mouse button so you can get out of stuck cases...

Here stand alone Win32 demo (compiled with **BDS2006 C++**).

- [Demo](https://ulozto.net/!5zYi6J7VYHr9/sliders-sover-exe) click on slow download below the big magenta button, enter 4 letter alphanumeric code to start download no registration needed.

For more info about how the solver Force computation works see related/followup QA:

- [Force directed layout for constrained rectangular shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41197710/2521214)

Comment: I appreciate your help, really. One of my attempts was with springs kinematic. but i realized that the precision of the final position of all elements depends from the number of iterations, and from the final "shake" which is in the most cases needed to avoid the jittery.around the stable state. Sadly, i need to avoid both.. But i agree with you, this could be a good solution.

Comment: Hi Spektre, do you have time to create a proof of concept? Maybe it could be a better one than mine...The example you provided hasn't constraint implementation i.e. node.left/right, and so on.

Comment: what do i have to click for a download? (btw, i am impressed.)

Comment: @NinaScholz if you want to try to code your approach (from your comments) then all you need is the `positions()` and `constraints(int ix);` they booth work as should (have tested with mouse) and for placement optimalization you can use something like this [How approximation search works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36163847/2521214) but the overall complexity will be most likely insane. Hope I did not forget to remove default RTL and package usage from the exe so it will not need anything.

Comment: @NinaScholz have updated code, demo link and animation with new version (have found/solve the interaction problem)

Comment: @deblocker updated answer have been missing shorter side parallel interactions and had also forget to rem out few lines in perpendicular interactions. Now it behaves as expected ... at least from mine point of view. Hope I did not delete something I should not as I hit answer size limit and was forced to remove debug draw stuff from source directly in the answer editor....

Comment: @Spektre: here is the JavaScript translation of your work: [Electrostatic 2-D Solver](https://jsfiddle.net/21qcxofd/) It works great, but sadly, i can't wait x seconds to know the final position of the structure :-(

Comment: @deblocker each iteration is just few micro seconds long so you can simulate seconds in matter of milliseconds ... just do not wait on timer or render ... You can also increase speed of solving by adjusting the constants ...

Comment: @deblocker also changing the rules might help. For example I use the strongest 1D force instead of directional 2D so the solver stabilize in one axis and then in another one and so on instead of all at once but I was too lazy to code it (it is quite more complex to implement that) btw nice to see you got it working :) +1 for that

Comment: @deblocker only mouse editation does not work ... selection is OK I see maybe you did not implement it on purpose or wrongly translated the mouse buttons extraction from the `VCL::TShiftState` Also the whole thing (code of mine I mean) is not optimized and can be improved a lot especially the `position()` recomputation can be enhanced a lot `constraints` too. I wanted to keep the code as simple as I could instead

Comment: @Spektre:  [strict loop](https://jsfiddle.net/21qcxofd/2/t) there are ~600 iterations, maybe could this be solved with less iterations? BTW, my friend, you know, it's always a matter of time..:) I love VCL.

Comment: You need to play with the charge and friction and velocity limits. Firstly without the `mode` changing charge so you can actually see how well it goes and to what velocity set those `mode` conditions. The bigger charge the faster it will go but you need to restrict velocity so it does not mess thing too much and also slow down on small enough distance ... Yu can use different limits for each `mode` not just changing charge as I did it is a lot to elaborate ...

Comment: @deblocker also if your final accuracy is in integers then you can stop much sooner then me ...

Comment: @Spektre: yes, i will approx to integers only. Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: @deblocker find `// precision control of solver` in code there is the precision control you can tweak the speeds even the number of modes ... to make it solve faster. Also if you want to tweak performance the biggest boost you would got if you add child/parrent lists to sliders so all of the `O(N^2)` searches will go to `O(N)` and `O(1)`. but even now `~600` iteartions should be done very quickly like in `<10 ms`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130613/discussion-between-deblocker-and-spektre).