# How can I manually create meshes in bevy with vertices?

Tags: rust, bevy

What do I have to do to to create a mesh for bevy with the following vertices:

```
let mut vertices : Vec<[f32; 3]> = Vec::new();

    vertices.push([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]);
    vertices.push([1.0, 2.0, 1.0]);
    vertices.push([2.0, 0.0, 0.0]);
```

I then want to spawn a MeshBundle like so

```
commands
    .spawn(MeshBundle {
        mesh: mesh,
        transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
        ..Default::default()
    });
```

Comment: Why is this Question getting donvoted?

Comment: Probably because there is no question in your post, and there’s no indication of what your problem is, or why the examples of code you have aren’t sufficient.

Comment: As a beginner wanting to develop procedural geometry, I believe I understand the gist of what this question is asking. I think, if the question lacks clarity, we should suggest edits rather than down-vote.

Comment: Also found it very insightful to see how the existing Bevy shapes have been constructed, for example the Box shape under: https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/main/crates/bevy_render/src/mesh/shape/mod.rs

And as a bonus, if you create your own shapes in a similar fashion, they'll be very reusable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This answer has been updated for the latest `bevy = "0.11"` and uses the default shaders.

The code below demonstrates how to:

1. Define vertex positions for a `bevy::render::pipeline::PrimitiveTopology::TriangleList`
2. Assign *vertex normals* and *uv coordinates* to the vertices
3. Create a triangle using the 3 vertices we defined

It is based on the built in shapes in bevy, which can be found [here](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/3b2c6ce49b3b9ea8bc5cb68f8d350a80ff928af6/crates/bevy_render/src/mesh/shape.rs#L224).

```rust
use bevy::prelude::*;
use bevy::render::mesh::{self, PrimitiveTopology};

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .insert_resource(Msaa::Sample4)
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_systems(Startup, setup)
        .run();
}

fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<StandardMaterial>>,
) {
    let mut mesh = Mesh::new(PrimitiveTopology::TriangleList);

    // Positions of the vertices
    // See https://bevy-cheatbook.github.io/features/coords.html
    mesh.insert_attribute(
        Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_POSITION,
        vec![[0., 0., 0.], [1., 2., 1.], [2., 0., 0.]],
    );

    // In this example, normals and UVs don't matter,
    // so we just use the same value for all of them
    mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, vec![[0., 1., 0.]; 3]);
    mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_UV_0, vec![[0., 0.]; 3]);

    // A triangle using vertices 0, 2, and 1.
    // Note: order matters. [0, 1, 2] will be flipped upside down, and you won't see it from behind!
    mesh.set_indices(Some(mesh::Indices::U32(vec![0, 2, 1])));

    commands.spawn(PbrBundle {
        mesh: meshes.add(mesh),
        material: materials.add(Color::rgb(0.3, 0.5, 0.3).into()),
        ..default()
    });

    commands.spawn(PointLightBundle {
        point_light: PointLight {
            intensity: 1500.0,
            shadows_enabled: true,
            ..default()
        },
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(4.0, 8.0, 4.0),
        ..default()
    });

    commands.spawn(Camera3dBundle {
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(-2.0, 2.5, 5.0).looking_at(Vec3::ZERO, Vec3::Y),
        ..default()
    });
}
```

You will have to define your own *positions*, *uvs* and *normals* according to your use case. Some shaders won't need all of these mesh attributes.

Comment: Optionally, for more complicated geometry, instead of setting normals manually with `mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,...)`, you can do: `mesh.duplicate_vertices(); mesh.compute_flat_normals();` after `mesh.set_indices(...)`. Note the warnings about increasing the vertex count.

Comment: @dim_voly looking great, juste curious why you need to `duplicate_vertices()` ?

Comment: @PhilippeParé It's because by default the normals are interpolated. You do have the option in WGSL to disable this using `flat` [interpolation](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#interpolation), but then all meshes rendered using that shader would loose the interpolated normals as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022613/how-to-implement-flat-shading-in-opengl-without-duplicate-vertices). So if you want to mix flat and smooth shaded meshes using the same shader, duplicating vertices is the only option you have.

Answer (score 4):

@frankenapps answer updated for `bevy = 0.7`

```
use bevy::prelude::*;
use bevy::render::mesh::{self, PrimitiveTopology};

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .insert_resource(Msaa { samples: 4 })
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_startup_system(setup)
        .run();
}

/// set up a simple 3D scene
fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<StandardMaterial>>,
    ) {
    let vertices = [
        ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]),
        ([1.0, 2.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]),
        ([2.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]),
    ];

    let indices = mesh::Indices::U32(vec![0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2]);

    let mut positions = Vec::new();
    let mut normals = Vec::new();
    let mut uvs = Vec::new();
    for (position, normal, uv) in vertices.iter() {
        positions.push(*position);
        normals.push(*normal);
        uvs.push(*uv);
    }

    let mut mesh = Mesh::new(PrimitiveTopology::TriangleList);
    mesh.set_indices(Some(indices));
    mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_POSITION, positions);
    mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, normals);
    mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_UV_0, uvs);

    // add entities to the world
    // plane
    commands.spawn_bundle(PbrBundle {
        mesh: meshes.add(mesh),
        material: materials.add(Color::rgb(0.3, 0.5, 0.3).into()),
        ..default()
    });
    // light
    commands.spawn_bundle(PointLightBundle {
        point_light: PointLight {
            intensity: 1500.0,
            shadows_enabled: true,
            ..default()
        },
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(4.0, 8.0, 4.0),
        ..default()
    });
    // camera
    commands.spawn_bundle(PerspectiveCameraBundle {
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(-2.0, 2.5, 5.0)
            .looking_at(Vec3::ZERO, Vec3::Y),
            ..default()
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the contribution! fyi usually with api updates we'd submit an edit instead of creating a new answer.. I still gave you a vote though :)