# How do I assign textures to 2D meshes in Bevy?

Tags: rust, mesh, bevy

I want to create hexagonal tiles similar to Civilization that I can click on the tiles and move things in and out of them with a drag and drop system. The code I've written throws an error after I run the program:

```
Mesh is missing requested attribute: Vertex_Normal (MeshVertexAttributeId(1), pipeline type: Some("bevy_sprite::mesh2d::material::Material2dPipeline<bevy_sprite::mesh2d::color_material::ColorMaterial>"))
```

I'm unsure as to why this throws an error since the program runs fine when I create a basic mesh from quad (`meshes.add(Mesh::from(shape::Quad::default())).into()`) but I want a 2D hexagon.

Here is my setup code:

```rust
fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<ColorMaterial>>,
    asset_server: Res<AssetServer>
) {
    let vertices = vec![
        [-0.8660, 0.5000],
        [ 0.8660, 0.5000],
        [-1.0000, 0.0000],
        [ 1.0000, 0.0000],
        [-0.8660,-0.5000],
        [ 0.8660,-0.5000]];
    let indeces = Indices::U16(vec![
        0, 1, 2,
        1, 3, 2,
        2, 3, 4,
        3, 5, 4
    ]);

    let mut mesh = Mesh::new(PrimitiveTopology::TriangleList);
    mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_POSITION, vertices);
    mesh.set_indices(Some(indeces));

    commands.spawn_bundle(OrthographicCameraBundle::new_2d());
    commands.spawn_bundle(MaterialMesh2dBundle {
        mesh: meshes.add(mesh).into(),
        transform: Transform::default().with_scale(Vec3::splat(128.)),
        material: materials.add(asset_server.load(TILE_SPRITE).into()),
        ..default()
    });
}
```

This is my main:

```rust
const TILE_SPRITE: &str = "tile.png";

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_startup_system(setup)
        .run();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the default shader in `bevy` your mesh must also have **normals** and **uvs** for each vertex.

You could either provide your own shader or add the required attributes, similar to the method shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66724123/4593433).

Apart from that it seems that the **positions** and **indices** you provided are incorrect. Even if you use bevy in 2D mode you still have to provide the positions using three coordinates (with `z` beeing set to zero). You can see what happens otherwise in the [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/) screenshot below:

[image: RenderDoc screenshot]

Here is a small sample with the corrected indices and positions, as well as placeholder values for UVs and normals, that should help you get started:

```rust
use bevy::{
    prelude::*,
    render::mesh::{Indices, PrimitiveTopology},
    sprite::MaterialMesh2dBundle,
};

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_startup_system(setup)
        .run();
}

fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<ColorMaterial>>,
    _asset_server: Res<AssetServer>,
) {
    let vertices = vec![
        [-0.8660, 0.5000, 0f32],
        [0.8660, 0.5000, 0f32],
        [-1.0000, 0.0000, 0f32],
        [1.0000, 0.0000, 0f32],
        [-0.8660, -0.5000, 0f32],
        [0.8660, -0.5000, 0f32],
    ];
    let normals = vec![
        [0f32, 0f32, 1f32],
        [0f32, 0f32, 1f32],
        [0f32, 0f32, 1f32],
        [0f32, 0f32, 1f32],
        [0f32, 0f32, 1f32],
        [0f32, 0f32, 1f32],
    ];
    let uvs = vec![
        [0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000],
    ];
    let indices = Indices::U16(vec![1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5]);

    let mut mesh = Mesh::new(PrimitiveTopology::TriangleList);
    mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_POSITION, vertices);
    mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, normals);
    mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_UV_0, uvs);
    mesh.set_indices(Some(indices));

    let mut camera = OrthographicCameraBundle::new_2d();
    camera.orthographic_projection.scale = 1f32;

    commands.spawn_bundle(camera);
    commands.spawn_bundle(MaterialMesh2dBundle {
        mesh: meshes.add(mesh).into(),
        transform: Transform::default().with_scale(Vec3::splat(128.)),
        material: materials.add(Color::rgb(0.3, 0.5, 0.3).into()),
        ..default()
    });
}
```

Please note, that in order for your Sprite to show up, you will have to change the UV coordinates (I did leave them at `0, 0`, because I do not know how you would like to map your sprite / texture to the hexagon).

Comment: Thank you, I feel like I recognize this from blender actually, my apologies if this was me being stupid