# Expected number of items (3D irregular shape) fit in 3d rectangular bin

Tags: algorithm, optimization, 3d, bulk, bin-packing

How to find expected number of items (3D irregular shape) fit in one Box (Bulk Packing)?

Look into below image example

[image: 1]

Each items have same dimension.
I am looking for simple algo for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

the obvious (and far from precise) limits are:

```
max = volume(bin) / volume(object)
min = volume(bin) / volume(OBB(object))
```

however the real number will be somewhere between the two. You could apply bin packing algorithms on your bin and objects however that would probably take too much time so instead I would use packing coefficient `k` so the computation time is not too big:

```
n = k*volume(bin) / volume(OBB(object))
```

Where `k` can be obtained on some "small" bin volume (while its dimensions are a multiple of object OBB) using any bin packing algorithm or simply measure it.

Comment: What is OBB? As per my knowledge, bin packing algo is only for 3d rectangular items.

Comment: @chessmaster [OBB is Oriented Bounding Box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62284464/2521214). No expert on the matter but Yes analytical Bin packing algorithms are for regular shapes or BBOX es however there are also stochastic (randomized position using RANSAC using gready approach) and [field simulation based approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42970086/2521214) (where you use gravity or charge based physics to pack into smallest possible volume) both can be combined ...